# riddle: "My beginning is foggy, / My middle is obscure, / My end is a riddle..."

Tags: riddle, word

Another riddle:

> My beginning is foggy,
> My middle is obscure,
> My end is a riddle.
> My past is winged,
> My present is dark,
> My future is stirred.
> What or who am I?

What is the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long shot, but are you

> MIST?

The trick being that

> the "beginning", "middle", and "end" are not the word's prefix, infix, and suffix, but actually all of them are the whole word!

*My beginning is foggy,*

> Mist is foggy by definition.

*My middle is obscure,*

> Mist makes things obscure.

*My end is a riddle.*

> Mist is (the answer to) this riddle.

*My past is winged,*

> [image: winged M]

*My present is dark,*

> **IS**, and this is a dark clue!

*My future is stirred.*

> **T**: tea is stirred.

What or who am I?